# ActiveRecord :include not working for belongs_to with foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include, belongs-to

I have a two models set up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # external_id column in database
end

class UserUpload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :primary_key => "external_id", :foreign_key => "external_user_id"
end
```

However, whenever I do

```
upload = UserUpload.find(id, :include => :user)
```

The sql that gets emitted is always looking for ID (and using zeros):

```
select * from users where id in (0,0,0,0 ... 0,0)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a problem using `foreign_keys` in a `belongs_to` relationship with `include`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just ran into this same problem. There's a [patch](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3208/a/281558/belongs_to_primary_key_lazy_load.patch) that applies to Rails 2.3.5 on [bug #3208](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3208-belongs_to-with-primary_key-does-not-work-with-finds-include) but it hasn't been applied to the [2-3-stable](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-3-stable) branch yet.

I have created a [monkey patch](http://gist.github.com/341979) for this bug as it is causing performance issues in my app. Place [fix_belongs_to_include_with_primary_key.rb](http://gist.github.com/raw/341979/14a3a86c5eea4c5deb8717e06bcf14fa69f1872e/fix_belongs_to_include_with_primary_key.rb) in your `config/inititalizers` directory and restart your app to apply it.

Comment: Thanks!  Glad to hear that I wasn't crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but option `:include` in `named_scope` makes `belongs_to` with `foreign_key` working.

```
named_scope :my_all, :include => :user
```